# Magento Variable Category Template

Tags: magento

I have numerous categories within my Magento store. Each of these categories can be described as 'Type A' or 'Type B'. I want each type of category to be displayed using a different template file. The templates are dynamic - loading in content from other sources given the category key being displayed.

To this end, when creating a category, an administrator should be able to set whether this category should be rendered as Type A or B. What is the best way of going about this?

The simplest solution I have come across so far is to create two static blocks 'Type A Block' and 'Type B Block' and dynamically load a template file into this using the following as described on [this blog post](http://mutinyworks.com/blog/2012/08/16/php-dynamic-content-in-a-static-block-magento/):

`{{block type="core/template" name="some_unique_name" template="myfolder/my_dynamic_php_content.phtml"}}`

This static block can then be assigned to the category and perform as I describe.

Although this may work, I'm a little uncomfortable with it as surely making static blocks dynamic is not what they are intended for. I'd prefer to make sure I develop this initial template in the most 'proper' way and so any help identifying how to best do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try out [**Magento Stack Exchange**](http://magento.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh oops. Did not know about that one!